# bootstrap table inside container div is out of browser width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a boostrap `container` div and inside it, I have a table:

```
<table id="reviewer_table" class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed tasks-table">
<thead>
  // tr/td ... 
</tbody>
</table>
```

But for some reason, this table is too wide, that one column is actually outside of the right screen.

I am not sure what is causing the issue, so I am sharing the code to know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: try to change the class of the container to `container-fluid`

Comment: or explicitly set max-width of your table to 100%

Comment: It is set to max-width: 100% - but I modified the dom and it does actually seem to change it... we'll see if this really is the solution since the table should somehow obey the parent properties

Comment: you can try to add class `row` to each `<tr>` element and a class `col-xs-?` to each `<td>` element directly or place them in divs

Comment: maybe those css styles for your table can also be useful `table-layout: fixed;`and `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: Yeah, one major problem I have is that the website renders without any issues on my laptop, but on my friends laptop there is a problem. An entire column disappears to the left, I don't have the chance to test it in his laptop and since it works on mine, I can only guess what the issue might be. But, I will try container-fluid I already zoomed in the page the get the effect my friend was getting the container-fluid fixed it.

Comment: I have this same problem. The "table-responsive" answers do not help as they only shrink the table down at smaller screen widths.

Answer (score 26):

Please add following div before your table

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
           Your table
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I don't understand why. According to bootstrap documents, table-responsive is supposed to be in table, not in parent div. Could you explain a bit why this works?

Comment: @Boat No you are wrong. According to bootstrap it needs to be added for div please follow the link it is from bootstrap 3 . Please read it. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-responsive

Comment: I see, I was checking the wrong documentation. In bootstrap 4 it should be in table. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/#responsive-tables

Comment: Comment above is outdated again: as of writing, bootstrap 4.5 says to create a wrapper element again: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/tables/#responsive-tables

Answer (score 12):

Add a class `table-responsive` in the table's parent div to achieve a responsive table.

Answer (score 8):

I also came across this problem. I think it happens when the content in the table (like long strings) extends further than the container is wide. [This post](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/) by CSS-Tricks helped me understand.

To fix it, I added table layout fixed to my CSS for the `<table>` like so (I only specified this for one use case with a class of `speaker-list`):

```
table.speaker-list {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

It defaults to equal-width columns, so you can put classes on the table headers `<th>` to specify different widths like 10% vs 40%. The CSS-tricks article has great examples.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4: add table-responsive in the table element and it will make the table to stay inside the div. The table will become horizontally scrollable

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe post the whole code of your table, as it is perfectly working for me.

```
<div class="container">
  <table id="reviewer_table" class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed tasks-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Password</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
      <td>asdsada</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Try it here: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Lubwfodc/)

Answer (score 0):

```
   **everything worked fine.**

      <div class="container">
       <table id="reviewer_table" class="table table-hover table-striped 
          table-condensed tasks-table">
         <thead>
            <tr> 
              <td>abc </td>
              <td> def</td>
              <td> ghi </td>
            </tr>
         </thead>

         <tbody>
           <td> jkl</td>
           <td> mno </td>
           <td>pqr</td>

        </tbody> 
        <tbody>
          <td> asdf</td>
          <td> adfd </td>
          <td>dfdf</td>

       </tbody> 


     </table>

    </div>


      [OUtput][1]

      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrCMK.jpg
```